# Revert entire directory back to certain period of time

Tags: git

I need to revert all files in 1 specific directory back to certain period of time (or git hash)

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git checkout <commit> -- <paths>`, where `<paths>` may be one or more directories and/or files to update those files in current working copy.
Then, if you want the revert to be permanent, make a new commit.

Comment: To answer the other half of the question, you can also do things like [`git checkout master@{yesterday} -- <paths>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse).